# Stubbing property getter prior to method on the same object - Rhino.Mocks 3.5

Tags: rhino-mocks

I have a possible bug scenario for Rhino.Mocks 3.5 here: http://groups.google.com/group/RhinoMocks/browse_thread/thread/b38d09b276e66ec7
Has anyone knows what's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug (my post at user group was answered http://groups.google.com/group/RhinoMocks/browse_thread/thread/b38d09b276e66ec7).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've been answered on that thread.  Did that help you and if so do you want to close this question?